# How to get rid of [1] when using paste() functions and RMarkdown PDFs

Tags: r, character, r-markdown

I am using paste() function to combine text with numbers and statistics using the paste() function.

However, when I knit the PDF in RMarkdown a `[1]` appears before this statement. Is there an option or different function that I can use to prevent this?

I am combined many lines so, having three or four [1]s can be distracting.

Tried using `cat()` and  `noquote()`

```
message<-paste("We examined",nrow(patients))
```

Actual:

```
[1] We examined 100 patients
```

Desired:

```
We examined 100 patients
```

Comment: I'm surprised you got a `[1]` with `cat()`. Can you please provide a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of what your rmarkdown file looks like?

Comment: For me `cat("We examined ",nrow(patients), " patients\n" )` works.

Comment: For some reason cat(paste()) didn't work well with noquote(). I switched to print()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of `cat` and `results="asis"` chunk option should help resolve your issue:

````
```{r results='asis'}
cat(paste("We examined", 100, "patients"))
```
````

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
write(message,stdout())
```